# Printer prints one or two pages then stops

Tags: printing

I'm working on Big Sur 11.6 with a Brother HLL23500W printer, connected over wifi.

If I print a multi-page document, very often the printer will print the first page or two pages, but then stop, with this message in the print queue:

```
Unable to add document to print job
```

There are no hardware or paper problems with the printer, and it will happily start printing another document.

I have no idea how to debug this - any ideas how to start?

Comment: I would start with plugging it into the printer directly and see if the problem still happens. Updating drivers and printer firmware are also good starts.